# ASP.NET URL-rewriting options

Tags: url-rewriting, asp.net-3.5

I've seen some .NET sites that obviously are using some sort of URL-rewriting method, but the one that intrigues me the most are ones that look like:

**http://www.somesite.com/pages/an-example-page.aspx**

I have previously used "UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewrite", but that requires that the database primary key integer be located somewhere in the requested URL.

Is there any other way to perform this? I am using ASP.NET 3.5

Thank u!

Comment: I've used UrlRewriting.Net many times - you don't have to include the PK as part of the URL

Comment: Hi Jason! Ok, when I had asked the developer, he emailed me back 2say that it can be done, 'tho not advisable as it would incur performance issues when querying the database against a string. That made sense, but have u experienced any performance issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a System.Web.Routing addition in the new MVC Framework you can use to do it in 3.5 or I believe it is included in the 3.5 SP1 install.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.aspx

Comment: This may be what I've been looking for...thanx for pointing me in this direction! I have also come across http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2008/03/11/aspnet-routing-goodbye-url-rewriting/

will post back here after I check it out

Comment: Thanx Tacoman667!! This seems to be the exact thing I've been searching for all along! It seems that IS possible to work with the routing component in isolation and independently to MVC - as im working with webforms. MVC has a dependency on the routing namespace.

Comment: You are quite welcome.  I am glad I am able to help out!  By the way, the MVC Framework is pretty awesome in my opinion, I highly suggest any ASP.NET developer go check it out!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/extensions/URLRewrite) for IIS 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ionic's Isapi Rewrite Filter (IIRF)](http://iirf.codeplex.com) on IIS5, IIS6, and IIS7.

Free, open source.  uses mod_rewrite-like syntax.  Works with ASPX, or PHP, or ASP, or whatever you run on the server. [Good documentation.](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/Iirf20Help/)